# use C++11 thread in cygwin doesn't work

Tags: c++11, cygwin, pthreads, c++14

Update:
Now, it is fine to compile pthread.cpp with

> -std=c++11

but cannot compile with

> -std=c++14

Why?

Origin:
pthread.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        thread thr{[]{cout<<1<<endl;}};
        thr.join();
}
```

When I compile the code

```
g++ -std=c++14 pthread.cpp
or
g++ -std=c++14 -pthread pthread.cpp
```

it doesn't return warnings or errors.
But when I execute a.exe, it returns nothing. (It should print 1 in screen.)
Do I miss something?
echo $?

```
127
```

g++ -v

```
...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: also add - Wall for warnings

Comment: @Mozfox still nothing

Comment: what if we give text like  thread thr{[]{cout<<"hello"<<endl;}};

Comment: @Mozfox still nothing.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11` works for me, but `g++ -std=c++14` fail.

Comment: @zakki You saved my life. But why cannot it compile by c++14?

Comment: I couldn't find the reason. cygwin gcc's bug?